# how to edit after the submit of form my link

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a form with two fields name and surname.
Write the fields and I click submit without action.
  BEfore the my site is `http://www.xn--nonlos-8wa.html`
The form is

```
    <form method="GET">
        <input type=”text” nome=”id” value=”qui il tuo testo”>
<input type=”text” cognome=”id” value=”qui il tuo testo”>
        <input type= "submit" name= "submit" value= "Invia" >
        </form>
```

The site after submit is:

```
http://www.xn--nonlos-8wa.html/?name=pollo&cognome=che+sono&nome=a&cognome=b&nome=c&cognome=d
```

This is the site where I have sent three form but now I would like to change the name of the second form that I sent.
Unless the data with the procedure that I read the site and subject to the variable.
I edit the field (variable) but as I'm going to rewrite on the site.
From name=a and surname=b that the site would become the new parameters.

```
http://www.xn--nonlos-8wa.html/?nome=pollo&cognome=che+sono&nome=565655&cognome=8765634&nome=c&cognome=d.
```

Then without using the submit of the form ...
HoW???
How do I edit the site by changing only the values ​​of interest?

Before the my site with the submit is

```
http://www.xn--nonlos-8wa.html/?name=pollo&cognome=che+sono&nome=a&cognome=b&nome=c&cognome=d
```

After with the script Javascrits (is possible??) is 
`http://www.xn--nonlos-8wa.html/?nome=pollo&cognome=che+sono&nome=565655&cognome=8765634&nome=c&cognome=d`

Comment: Errm. Translation problems. Can you rephrase what you're asking? It's not very clear.

Comment: He's wondering why his form action includes nome and cognome (first and last name) multiple times, each time he submits the form. The reason is because he hasn't defined an action attribute on his form element.

Comment: no,,,,,
I change the name of the site...
Before 
http://www.xn--nonlos-8wa.html/?name=pollo&cognome=che+sono&nome=a&cognome=b&nome=c&cognome=d
After
http://www.xn--nonlos-8wa.html/?nome=pollo&cognome=che+sono&nome=565655&cognome=8765634&nome=c&cognome=d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might have been translation problems with your question, but I think you're asking how to set the names of the parameters you pass from your form?

The easiest thing to do would just be to change the name of you inputs:

```
<input type=”text” name=”surname” value=”qui il tuo testo”>
```

But if you can't edit the html for some reason, you could also send the request with jQuery and set the parameters in a json object:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.xn--nonlos-8wa.html/",
    data: {name: "a", surname:"b"}
});
```

Comment: Interesting...
But how to change the second fields....
Because i want to change the value of site (look at the question) ut how??

Comment: Still not sure what you're asking... You can change the url that you send the call to dynamically, just set the url parameter in $.ajax()

Answer (score 0):

You must explicitly define the URL that your form submits to, otherwise the form action becomes whatever is in the URL and will duplicate your querystring variables.

```
<form method="GET" action="testo.html">
    ...
</form>
```

Then it will go to testo.html?nome=pollo&cognome=che+sono.

Of course, you can change "testo.html" to whatever page your test is actually on.

Comment: Jordan no.... 
But how to change the second fields.... Because i want to change the value but how??